# Probability statement with line breaks

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

In Katz's textbook on digital signatures in Definition 8.4, there is the following statement:

[image: Multiline probability]

How can I break the lines within a `\prob` statement as pictured?

Comment: You can use a `bmatrix`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, its a good suggestion, but the colon would not align as nicely, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `array`s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}% for the Times-like font, though I'd prefer newtxtext+newtxmath
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\operatorname{Pr}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
(pk,sk) \gets \mathsf{Gen}(1^k) \\
(I,c_1,r_1,c_2,r_2) \gets A(pk)
\end{array}
:
\begin{array}{c}
c_1 \neq c_2 \\
\text{and}\\
(pk,I,c_1,r_1), (pk,I,c_2,r_2) \\
\text{are both accepting transcripts}
\end{array}
\right].
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `bmatrix` (as suggested @Bernard in his comment) and `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% for the Times-like font, though I'd prefer newtxtext+newtxmath
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\operatorname{Pr}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{gathered}
(pk,sk) \gets \mathsf{Gen}(1^k) \\
(I,c_1,r_1,c_2,r_2) \gets A(pk)
    \end{gathered}
    & : &   \begin{gathered}
c_1 \neq c_2 \\
\text{and}\\
(pk,I,c_1,r_1), (pk,I,c_2,r_2) \\
\text{are both accepting transcripts}
            \end{gathered}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gathered is a nice idea! (+1)

Comment: @Bernard, thank you very much! Your answer (+1)is also innovative!

Answer (score 2):

Still another possibility with `\DeclarePairedDelimitersXPP` from `mathtools` and `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Prob[1]{\operatorname{Pr}}[]{}{#1}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\[
\Prob*{\Vectorstack{(pk,sk) \gets \mathsf{Gen}(1^k) \\
(I,c_1,r_1,c_2,r_2) \gets A(pk) }
 \, : \,\Vectorstack{c_1 \neq c_2 \\
\text{and}\\
(pk,I,c_1,r_1), (pk,I,c_2,r_2) \\
\text{are both accepting transcripts}}
}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]